# multiple method call same single service with cachefactory in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a service like below... which always get all types  of buyers from server.

```
var buyersService = function ($http, $q,$cacheFactory) {
            var serviceBase = '/api/OMData/';
            var  BuyersFactory = {};
            buyersService.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');

            BuyersFactory.GetBuyers = function (type) {
              var buyersDiffer = $q.defer();
              var dataList =  buyersService.cache.get('BuyerData');
              if (dataList != null && dataList.length > 0) {
                  buyersDiffer .resolve(_getBuyerByType(type,dataList));
              }
              else {
                  $http.get(serviceBase + 'GetBuyers').then(
                   function (results) {
                       buyersService.cache.put("BuyerData", results.data);
                       buyersDiffer .resolve(_getBuyerByType(type,results.data));
                   });
              }
              return buyersDiffer .promise;
            }

    app.factory('OMDataService', ['$http', '$q', '$cacheFactory', buyersService]);

});



function _getBuyerByType(Type,dataList) {
        try {

            var typedBuyer= Enumerable.From(dataList).Where(function (x) {
                return x.Type== Type;
            }).ToArray();
            return typedBuyer;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }


 function getLocalBuyer(){
        return BuyersFactory.GetBuyers(1);
    }

   function getForeignBuyer(){
        return BuyersFactory.GetBuyers(2);
    }
```

There are two types of buyer in my business. Such as localBuyer and foreignBuyer. In my controller I need to call two service at a time with Q.All. When two service hit in buyersService method then system call server two times. Hence current cash is empty. **But I want that system call server one times for one service call and second service  get data from cache.**

**EDIT: Controller code**

```
function loadDefaultData() {
    try {
        $q.all([
            OMDataService.getLocalBuyer(),
            OMDataService.getForeignBuyer(),

        ]).then(function (data) {
            $timeout(function () {
                //set dropdown list
                viewData.local= data[0];
                viewData.foreign= data[1];

            }, 0);
        }).catch(function (e) {
            showError(e);
        });

    } catch (e) {
        showError(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The controller code you posted is incomplete, where does `generalSetupSvc` come from?

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look and update my answer

Comment: These functions `getLocalBuyer` `getForeignBuyer`  `getItemTypesByItemID ` are not defined in your factory

Comment: ok, I am writing such method in my factory

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining a variable to save the promise returned by $http. The first time the service is called, that variable is initially undefined. It is set to the promise returned by $http.

The logic of your service thus becomes:

1. if cache, return cache
2. if promise, return promise
3. else call server and save promise

I removed you deferred variable. It is no more needed. I did wrap the cache response in $q.when() (doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
var buyersService = function ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {
    var serviceBase = '/api/OMData/';
    var  BuyersFactory = {};
    buyersService.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');

    var serverPromise; // Will be used to store the promise returned by $http on first server call

    BuyersFactory.GetBuyers = function (type) {
        var dataList =  buyersService.cache.get('BuyerData');

        function serverCall () { // stores promise receives by $http and return it
            serverPromise = $http.get(serviceBase + 'GetBuyers').then(
                function (results) {
                    buyersService.cache.put("BuyerData", results.data);
                    return _getBuyerByType(type, results.data);
                });
            return serverPromise;
        }

        if (dataList !== null && dataList.length > 0) {
            return $q.when(_getBuyerByType(type,dataList)); // auto resolving promise
        }

        // If a first call to the server was already done, serverPromise will exist and no further call to the server will be made
        return serverPromise || serverCall();
    };

    app.factory('OMDataService', ['$http', '$q', '$cacheFactory', buyersService]);

});



function _getBuyerByType(Type,dataList) {
    try {

        var typedBuyer= Enumerable.From(dataList).Where(function (x) {
            return x.Type== Type;
        }).ToArray();
        return typedBuyer;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: When my second call appear then I cannot found any data. Because  "if (dataList !== null && dataList.length > 0) " will false. And ServerPromise already defined for first call.

Comment: Please show me your controller code. I have successfully used this technique in many situations. Rgds

Comment: @AminUddin you edited the answer instead of the question, I presume by mistake. I added your controller code (from the suggested edit) to your question.